# why I can't change the value of the variable?

Tags: dart

origin code:

```
num age = 16;
age=18;
```

> the error info is "Variables must be declared using the keywords
> 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name. Try adding the name of the
> type of the variable or the keyword 'var'."

I don't know how to solve this

I've change var to dynamic, but it didn't help

Comment: Dart isn't a REPL language like JavaScript or Python. As a general rule, only declarations can be in top level or class level scopes. Executing code has to go in a function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the age inside of a function like this:

```
 num age = 16;

  void changeAge() {
    age = 18;
  }
```

If you try to change the assignment outside of a function, Dart thinks you're trying to create a new variable.